# pandas.ewma to be used to make prediction

Tags: exponential-smoothing, moving-average, pandas

I would like to implement EWMA to be able to make prediction based on historical data.

I am using EWMA in pandas. After playing with com and span, it seems like predictions are not based on historical data and smoothing is done based on current and future data.

[image]

Am I using the correct parameters?